# Understanding the $\operatorname{Hom}_A(T \otimes_B W, V) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(W, \operatorname{Hom}_A(T,V))$ isomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, bimodules

Peter Webb in his book on Representation theory states that if $T$ is an $(A,B)$-module, $V$ is an $A$-module, $W$ is a $B$-module, then 
$\operatorname{Hom}_A(T \otimes_B W, V) \cong \operatorname{Hom}_B(W, \operatorname{Hom}_A(T,V))$.

He also gives the mutually inverse maps:

$$f\mapsto(w\mapsto(t\mapsto f(t\otimes w)))$$
and
$$(t\otimes w \mapsto g(w)(t)) \leftarrow\!\shortmid g$$

How exactly do I check if these are mutually inverse?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Its basically currying, but applied to bilinear maps rather than to functions of two variables. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying

Answer (score 1):

You can check that directly. For example, let $g$ be the map $w\mapsto(t\mapsto f(t\otimes w))$. Then what is the map $h:t\otimes w \mapsto g(w)(t)$? Since 
$$g(w)(t)=f(t\otimes w),$$
$h$ is the same as $f$. The other way is very similar.